# angular No value accessor Error with child component

Tags: javascript, angular, formgroups

My loginform is has 2 childs components (one for email and one for password).

I use formGroup to store input entries. On loading I have an error

- "No value accessor for form control name: 'email'"
- "No value accessor for form control name: 'password'.
  and some informations are missing on display.

After clicking submit button, missing informations appear on the screen and submit is working

My code:

> html parent

```js
<form [formGroup]="loginFormGroup" (submit)="validateLoginData()">     
      <div class="login">
        <!--button container-->
        <div class="login__input__container">

          <!-- login-->
          <app-input
            [formGroup]="loginFormGroup"       
            type="text"                  
            formControlName="email"           
            placeHolder="mon@email.fr"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            labelText="email"
          ></app-input>          

          <!-- password-->
          <app-input
            [formGroup]="loginFormGroup"       
            type="password"                  
            formControlName="password"           
            placeHolder="mot de passe"
            name="password"
            id="password"
            labelText="password"
          ></app-input>  
        </div>
        <div class="login__button__container">
          <input type="submit" value="se connecter">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

> ts parent

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeLoginFormGroup();
  }

  /**
   * Construction du formgroup
   */
  initializeLoginFormGroup() {    
    this.loginFormGroup = this.fb.group({     
      // Email
      email: ['', Validators.required],

      // Password
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
```

> html child

```js
<div class="input__group" [formGroup]="formGroup">  
  <label class="input__label" [for]="id">{{labelText}}</label>
  <input
    class="input"
    [type]="type" 
    [formControlName]="formControlName"   
    [placeholder]="placeHolder"
    [name]="name" 
    [id]="id"
  >
  <!-- Erreur Message-->
  <div>
    <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> ts child

```js
export class InputComponent {
 
  @Input() id: string = '';

  @Input() type: string = '';

  @Input() formControlName: string = '';

  @Input() placeHolder: string = '';

  @Input() name: string = '';

  @Input() errorMessage: string ='';

  @Input() labelText: string = ''

  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
}
```

Hope you can help to solve this error

Comment: You must implement ControValueAccessor in the app-input component https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Maybe this article helps: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I've to implement controlValueAccessor to make work my formControl.

Here is my updated code with error event:

> html child

```js
<div class="input__group" [formGroup]="formGroup">  
  <label class="input__label" [for]="id">{{labelText}}</label>
  <input #input
    [class.border--error]="formGroup.get(formControlName)?.touched && formGroup.get(formControlName)?.errors?.['required']"
    class="input"
    [type]="type" 
    [formControlName]="formControlName"   
    [placeholder]="placeHolder"
    [name]="name" 
    [id]="id"
  >
  <!-- Erreur Message-->
  <div *ngIf="formGroup.get(formControlName)?.touched && formGroup.get(formControlName)?.errors?.['required']">
    <p>{{errorMessage}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> ts child

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.css'],
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class InputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @ViewChild('input', {static: false}) input!: ElementRef;

  @Input() autoFocus = false;

  @Input() id: string = '';

  @Input() type: string = '';

  @Input() formControlName: string = '';

  @Input() placeHolder: string = '';

  @Input() name: string = '';

  @Input() errorMessage: string ='';

  @Input() labelText: string = ''

  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if(this.autoFocus) {
      this.onFocus()
    }
  }

  //#region ControlValueAccessor
    value = '';

    @Input() isDisabled!: boolean;

    onChange!: (value?: any) => void;

    onTouch!: (event: any) => void;

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
      this.value = obj;
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
      this.onChange = fn
    }  

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
      this.onTouch = fn
    }

    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
      this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    }
    
    onInput(value: any) {
      if(this.onChange) {
        this.onChange(value);
      }
    }

    onTouched(value: any) {
      if(this.onTouch) {
        this.onTouch(value)
      }
    }
   
  //#endregion
  

  onFocus() {
    //Normal Focus Method
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();

    // Another Method for set Focus
    //  this.input.nativeElement.select();
  }
}
```

thanks for your help

Cyrille